# two separate observe() functions watching two different elements don't watch them

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, intersection-observer

I can't think of a better title but this is the situation:

I want to watch two different elements in an intersection observer. On page has one element

My code at first looked like below:

```
  // page 1 element to watch
  const titleEl = document.querySelector('.table-header')
  // page 2 element to watch
  const pdTitleEl = document.querySelector('#section h2')
  const stickyPageEl = document.querySelector('.pagination-links--sticky')

  const handler = (entries) => {
    if (!entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      stickyPageEl.classList.add('dropdown-shadow')
    } else {
      stickyPageEl.classList.remove('dropdown-shadow')
    }
  }
  const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(handler)
  // page 1 observer 
  observer.observe(titleEl)
  // page 2 observer 
  observer.observe(pdTitleEl)
```

My expectation was that it would watch both and wether one was intersection it would add a class. That was not the case. I got:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on
>   'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

I don't know what this means. What is "parameter 1"?

The piece that got me thinking:

> is not of type 'Element'.

I tried this:

```
  // page 1 element to watch
  const titleEl = document.querySelector('.table-header')
  // page 2 element to watch
  const pdTitleEl = document.querySelector('#section h2')
  const stickyPageEl = document.querySelector('.pagination-links--sticky')

  const handler = (entries) => {
    if ((!entries[0].isIntersecting) && (titleEl)) {
  stickyPageEl.classList.add('dropdown-shadow')
} else if ((!entries[0].isIntersecting) && (pdTitleEl)) {
  stickyPageEl.classList.add('dropdown-shadow')
} 
else {
  stickyPageEl.classList.remove('dropdown-shadow')
}
  }
  const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(handler)
  // page 1 observer 
  observer.observe(titleEl)
  // page 2 observer 
  observer.observe(pdTitleEl)
```

Which I think checks to see if they exist first but I still get the same error.

Can you run multiple `observe()` functions on different elements or is that not how this works?

**EDIT**

As commenter and myself noted in question this seems to be related to elements not existing in DOM which makes sense.

```
  // page 1 element to watch
  const titleEl = document.querySelector('.table-header')
  // page 2 element to watch
  const pdTitleEl = document.querySelector('#section h2')
  const stickyPageEl = document.querySelector('.pagination-links--sticky')

  const handler = (entries) => {
    if ((!entries[0].isIntersecting) && (titleEl != null)) {
  stickyPageEl.classList.add('dropdown-shadow')
} else if ((!entries[0].isIntersecting) && (pdTitleEl != null)) {
  stickyPageEl.classList.add('dropdown-shadow')
} 
else {
  stickyPageEl.classList.remove('dropdown-shadow')
}
  }
  const observer = new window.IntersectionObserver(handler)
  // page 1 observer 
  observer.observe(titleEl)
  // page 2 observer 
  observer.observe(pdTitleEl)
```

Doesn't work either.

Why?

Comment: The error says the first parameter is not an element. Most likely it's `null` or `undefined` caused by the fact that the selector didn't match anything in DOM.

Comment: Right - that seems to be the problem. Shouldn't my second block be a step in the right direction then...?

Comment: You need to perform this check before observing. Depending on your setup you may need to wait for the elements to appear in DOM by using MutationObserver or a periodic check inside setInterval.

Comment: @wOxxOm this script that runs runs after the dom is loaded - the script tag is in the footer of the page

Comment: Well, debug it in devtools.

Comment: ....I did, which is why I'm asking this question in the first place! I get the error which doesn't mean anything (It seems that its a dom loaded issue?) Google search is useless, other questions on this topic aren't helpful. If you can't help then I'll ask elsewhere.

Comment: There's simply no other explanation for the error. Without trying the extension locally there's nothing one can do to help.